# What does left composition mean in this question?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the vector space of all linear transformations $L(V,V)$ on the vector space $(V,K)$ and a linear map $F:L(V,V)\to L(V,V)$ such that $F(a)= b \circ a$ for all $a\in L(V,V)$, where $b\in L(V,V)$ is fixed. In other words $F$ is the left composition by some fixed linear transformation $b$. Under which conditions on $b$ is $a$ invertible?

In $b \circ a$ the $\circ$ is functional composition.

Answer (score 1):

Since $b$ is a function from $V$ to $V$, and $a$ is a function from $V$ to $V$, we can make a new function from $V$ to $V$ by setting $(b \circ a)(x) = b(a(x))$. This is what the "functional composition" is. If you had a basis for your vector space, and wrote out $b$ and $a$ as matricies, this would just be matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your response. yes i understand that but how can F(a)= b o a?

Comment: To define a function $F:L(V,V) \rightarrow L(V,V)$, I have to tell you how to take a thing $a$ in $L(V,V)$ and build a thing $F(a)$ in $L(V,V)$. A thing in $L(V,V)$ needs to be a function from $V$ to $V$, so we need to know what $F(a)$ does to $x \in V$. I'll just say that $F(a)$ sends $x$ to the same thing that $b(a(x))$ does. So $(F(a))(x) = b(a(x)).$ But $b(a(x)) = (b \circ a)(x)$, so for shorthand we write $F(a) = b \circ a$. We also need to show that $F(a)$ is linear, and so on. But that's what the definition is.

Comment: oh thank you Zach L. So under what conditions on b is a invertible?